# How to change from the default shell authenticating using SSSD/AD

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, redhat, sssd

Within in the `sssd.conf` file, does anyone know what the syntax should be to allow me to switch between different login shells?

Thanks

```
example@example.com:~$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Password:
chsh: user 'example' does not exist in /etc/passw
```

Comment: Do you want to set a different default shell or change shells mid-session?

Comment: Are you using ldap / freeipa services? Tell us more about your environment

Comment: I would like to change shells mid session and I'm using Active Directory. Running Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Comment: @d3code2016 the error `chsh: user 'example' does not exist in /etc/passwd`  suggests that there is no user in `/etc/passwd` which is correct. If you have a central container like `ldap` that holds all objects like 'users', 'passwords', 'computers' etc.. then that's where you've to look for. What does `/etc/nsswitch.conf` show?  And you are better off asking your ldap admin to modify your shell. There might be restrictions.

Comment: # `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.
passwd:         compat sss
group:            compat sss
shadow:         compat sss

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:     files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:          db files
rpc:               db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the file /etc/sssd/sssd.conf and override the default shell in the domain section of the file :

```
[domain/YOUR_DOMAIN]
override_shell = /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

using `override_shell` changed shell for everyone.

In AD you can add the unix shell it uses the attribute `loginShell`
Open the user in AD Users and Computers 
click on the attribute tab and look for `loginShell` and edit that to the desired shell for the user

then in sssd.conf I add the line 
`shell_fallback = /bin/zsh` that way if your user doesn't have a shell in AD they still get a shell.
I also did add `ldap_schema = ad` to sssd.conf to force Active Directory schema.

Comment: I also had to clear the cache the hard way (`systemctl stop sssd && rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/* && systemctl restart sssd`, `sss_cache -E` did NOT work), then logout and log back in before it got applied.

Answer (score 1):

If this is FreeIPA, use the IPA command:

```
ipa user-mod  username --shell=/bin/bash
```

By default users can modify themselves.